# Trouble using socket.socket() when sending HTTP POST command to Vulnerable WebServer

Tags: python-2.7, exploit

I've been tinkering with a webserver exploit over the last we days, and I am stumped on a portion in Python.  I wrote a malformed http POST data in python, and when I paste it into Http Live Headers and replay the request, it works 100 out of 100 times.

Problem is when I try to remove the Replay headers portion and just use python to do the entire thing, python doesn't seem to be sending the full POST command.

I'm using this:

```
send = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
send.connect(('hostname', 80))
send.send(PostCommand)
send.close()
```

The PostCommand is ~36000 characters.  When I look at the stack after the Python method, it is at least able to cause an exception but not send enough data to overwrite SEH.  Every time a different amount of information is making it to the web server.

Is there possibly a parameter that I'm missing to force Python to send the entire command, or is it just that HTTP Headers is just doing something in the background that I'm not realizing?

I'm writing the PostCommand to disk before sending, below is what it looks like:

```
POST /PATH HTTP/1.1
Host: hostname 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://hostname/path.htm
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1234567890
Content-Length: 139
If-Modified-Since: *

-----------------------------1234567890



AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA... (continued to 36000+)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `socket.send()` method will write as much as it can, up to the size of the buffer you give it. But for many reasons, the number of bytes written may be less than the buffer size.

Applications are always responsible for checking that the full buffer was written, and to re-send it themselves if they need. This comes from the underlying C socket library. See `man send(2)`, or the documentation for the `socket.send()` method.

The way to do this is usually:

```
nsent = 0
while nsent < len(buffer):
    nsent += sock.send(buffer[nsent])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I've fooled around with what you said a little, but still can't get it to work.  I've tried taking out socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM and tried a few others, but still having the same problem.  I also added your snip to my code, no luck.  Thanks though!

Comment: Those options are required to get a TCP socket, which is the underlying transport protocol below HTTP. They're also the default. I'm not sure what's going on, in that case, but your solution of using an HTTP library directly is a good one. The `requests` library is excellent for Python client-side development.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using httplib, and that seems to work perfectly, every time.

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("hostname",80)
conn.request("POST", "/Path", PostCommand)
```